# Google analytics reporting link as campaign instead of referral

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, feeds, referrer, feedburner

There are several websites which link to my blog posts but are using links from feedburner (similar too http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/AboutMyCode/~3/something ) so when someone visits these links it gets reported in Google Analytics as campaign. Is there any way to make these links show as Referral in traffic sources?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible. And the problem is not on the link you describe but on the parameters that link ads to the final URL something like:

```
?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+UsefulUsability+(Useful+Usability)&utm_content=Google+Reader
```

You can prevent future users to link to you using this Google Analytics campaign links by writing a JavaScript that removes al utm_... stuff out of the URL. If the script does this just after Google Analytics script finish running on your pages it will not affect how Google Analytics gets user data.

Because users typically link to a page after reading it they rarely, if ever, copy the link with the utm parameters.